# Need to access data from xlsx file

Tags: java, eclipse, xlsx

```
public class fileReader {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException {
        String excelFilePath = "sample.xlsx";
        InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            Row nextRow = iterator.next();
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();
        ...
```

In the XSSFWorkbook line the error has been showing

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlOptions.setEntityExpansionLimit(I)Lorg/apache/xmlbeans/XmlOptions;
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLFactory.createDocumentPart(POIXMLFactory.java:66)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart.read(POIXMLDocumentPart.java:657)
    at org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:180)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:282)
    at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook.<init>(XSSFWorkbook.java:303)
    at fileReader.main(fileReader.java:20)
```

Comment: Can you [edit] to show us the error ? But to read a file, you need to provide a `File` to the workbook instance using [`Workbook(File)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook-java.io.File-) or [`Workbook(InputStream)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook-java.io.InputStream-)

Comment: If File is given to the workbook instance then there occurs an error showing File cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: Which import is missing?

Comment: Can you also add the list of jar you have included ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not reading your file. You are creating a new workbook. SO I suspect your are getting an exception because your are asking for a `Sheet` where there is none.

Provide your file to the instance using [`XSSFWorkbook(File)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook-java.io.File-)

```
String excelFilePath = "sample.xlsx";
File f = new File(excelFilePath);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(f);
```

Or [`XSSFWorkbook(InputStream)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook-java.io.InputStream-)

```
String excelFilePath = "sample.xlsx";
File f = new File(excelFilePath);
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(f);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
```

---

> If File is given to the workbook instance then there occurs an error showing File cannot be resolved to a type

Just need to import `java.io.File`

Comment: No it is not, your code is  `XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();`

Comment: XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream); //if its given like this another error is showing like The constructor XSSFWorkbook(InputStream) is undefined

Comment: poi bin-4.1.0 latest version downloded from Apache POI

Comment: Well then you should check your import and clean your project because [`XSSFWorkbook(InputStream)`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/4.1/org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook.html#XSSFWorkbook-java.io.InputStream-)  is defined in 4.1. You should find at least `import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook` and `java.io.InputStream`

Comment: Is poi bin-4.1.0 only to be used or any other jar to be included to run this program?

Comment: You need to include almost every jar present in the archive downloaded on Apache website. Including the folders `lib` and `ooxml-lib`

Comment: Now i have created a fresh project and used the same code.Then included the poi bin 4.1.0 ,poi-ooxml,xml beans jar files.Then File has been given to the workbook instance,now there is no error.But while running,it shows //Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/ListValuedMap

Comment: Because it needs **almost every jar** in the archive you download. This one is the collection jar, but basically, you need to import more than 10 library.

Comment: Do that folder named docs also to be added??All other files have been added.

Comment: No, docs are documentation. Not libraries. See the comment in the question

Comment: Thanks, i have created it again as a fresh project. Now its working.